# Twitter Bootstrap 3 inline and horizontal form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to migrate my Bootstrap 2 form to Bootstrap 3.
My current code and fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/Z4TRx/

```css
.navbar-sam-main .navbar-toggle{
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="" id="myDialog1">

    <div class="" id="myDialog2">

        <form role="form" class="" id="contactForm" onsubmit="send(); return false;">
            <label>Please fill the form</label>
            <br/><br/>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">My Label 2</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required="required" value="myName">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">My Label 3</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required="required">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">My Label 4</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" required="required"></textarea>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" style="margin-left: 40px">Send</button>
        </form>

    </div>


</div>
```

I want inline behaviour, my label 2 will be next to text input, my label 3 will be next to text input. I also need horizontal behaviour, my label 4 will be on top of the textarea. My label 2's and my label 3's text box will be 4 column width, my label 4's width will be full width of the form.

[image]

How can I do this in Bootstrap 3 ?

Comment: Perfectly described here - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Add col-*-* classes to your labels and input wrapping divs.

Comment: my only concern is not adding col--. inline + horizontal at the same time doesn't written in docs.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just because the docs suggest you should use the form controls does not mean you have to. You can just use the built-in grid system to achieve the layout. See http://bootply.com/82900 for a working example. Code below:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="row">
      <label class="col-xs-4" for="inputEmail1">Email</label>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <label class="col-xs-4" for="inputPassword1">Password</label>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <label class="col-xs-12" for="TextArea">Text Area</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="TextArea"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Screenshot of above code rendered:
[image: Screenshot of above code rendered]

UPDATE: Just realized I dropped the label tags. Updated the answer, swapping `<label>` for `<div>`.

UPDATE: Updating code to reflect need to stay in this layout in small widths, as requested in comments below. See [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xxUV/3) for a working example.

Comment: In big screens this works. But if screen is not wide again input fields goes next line. Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8xxUV/1/

Comment: I show this dialog page in a lightbox dialog, so my lightbox width is nearly 600px.

Comment: Then just change all the `col-md-*` to `col-sm-*` or `col-xs-*`. http://jsfiddle.net/8xxUV/2/ shows it with `col-xs-*`. I also had to change column count a bit to make sure the labels were not getting overlapped by the inputs.

Comment: Also, since you are showing this in some sort of modal, I would switch the column widths to take up the full width of the dialog. See http://jsfiddle.net/8xxUV/3/ as another alternative.

Comment: Thank you. That's fully what I need. As a sidenote, textarea height was very small for me. So I added this for future: ```< textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" required="required" style="height: 150px;" > < /textarea >```

Comment: Just for future reference, inline styles are usually not a good idea. If I were coding this, I would target `<textarea>`'s in the stylesheet. Something like `.modal textarea { height:150px; }` (adjust for your modal classes as necessary). This would target any textarea in a modal, keeping them consistent throughout.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is not really in-line behaviour at all, just horizontal.

This code should help:

```
<div class="" id="myDialog1">
    <div class="" id="myDialog2">
        <form role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="contactForm" onsubmit="send(); return false;">
            <label>Please fill the form</label>
            <br><br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">My Label 2</label>
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-7">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required="required" value="myName">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">My Label 3</label>
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-7">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required="required">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message" class="col-lg-3">My Label 4</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-10">
                     <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" required="required"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" style="margin-left: 20px">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And looks like this:

[image: horizontal form]

The `col-sm-*` tags are optional - they just stop the elements from stacking as you size the window down.

You can try it out here: http://bootply.com/82889

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, here is my solution:

```
<form method="post" class="col-md-12 form-inline form-horizontal" role="form">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="jbe"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> Email me things like this: </label>
        <div class="input-group col-sm-7">
            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="your.email@example.com"/>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
```

here is the **[Demo](http://bootply.com/98453)**

Answer (score 1):

you can try the code below

```
<div class="" id="myDialog1">



        <form role="form" class="" id="contactForm" onsubmit="send(); return false;">
            <div class="clearfix igr col-md-12">
                <label>Please fill the form</label>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix igr col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="name">My Label 2</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required="required" value="myName">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix igr col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label for="email">My Label 3</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required="required">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix igr col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="message">My Label 4</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" required="required"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix igr col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" id="submit" >Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

and use the styles as:

```
label,textarea{
        margin:5px 0;
    }
    .igr{
        margin:15px 0;
    }
```

Comment: Also this solution doesn't work for small screens. Please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/jLgTe/1/ Form creates new lines.

Comment: In order for the solution to be working in small screens use col-sm* instead of col-md*

Answer (score -1):

Adding the class `control-label` to your labels should do the trick for you.